# Updating cluster distance in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, clustering

I have a vector layer with clustering in OL3.4:

```
cluster = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Cluster({
            distance: 20,
            source: some_geojson
          }),
          style: some_style,
});
```

I want to change the cluster 'distance' property, after some event, particularly:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution',function(){
    // change cluster distance here (and refresh it)
}
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't directly change the `distance` property on an `ol.source.Cluster`.

You've 2 solutions I think:

1) first idea: on `change:resolution` event set a new source to your layer:

`map.getView().on('change:resolution',function(){ 
  cluster.setSource(new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    source: some_geojson
  })
);`

2) Defines multiple layers which are displayed at different resolutions:

```
cluster1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  minResolution: 200,
  maxResolution: 2000
  source: new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 20,
    source: some_geojson
  }),
  style: some_style,
});
cluster2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  minResolution: 2000,
  maxResolution: 20000
  source: new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    source: some_geojson
  }),
  style: some_style,
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but if anyone stumbles upon this in the future, this is a working example of clustered features with variable distance based on the slider shown:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Specifically, the code to set the distance is clusterSource.setDistance(distance). This is how it's used in the example above, using a slider called `distance`:

`distance.addEventListener('input', function() {
  clusterSource.setDistance(parseInt(distance.value, 10));
});`

(OpenLayers 4.3.1, working as of 8/16/2017)